# AWS Linux sudo: unable to resolve host

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, sudo, hostname

I have a problem when launching any instance (from and AMI) within a particular VPC. Everytime I type a "sudo" command, I get the following:

sudo: unable to resolve host ip-xxx-xx-x-xxx

I have seen many posts on the internet about this and they all mention the following two solutions:

- **Manually edit the /etc/hosts file on every server**... This is not practical (especially when using AutoScaling to generate new instances) and I shouldn't have to do this as I don't have to do this for any instances on other VPCs
- **Turn on "DNS hostnames" on the VPC**... I have done this and it hasn't made a difference. I have gone through all the settings on the VPC (and route tables, subnets etc) and I have it set exactly the same way as a "working" VPC on my account. Still no luck

Any help here?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if this is an AWS specific problem that has been run into before, it stems from not enabling `enableDnsHostnames` in your VPC configuration.

Here is a link to the AWS documentation that talks about this.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-updating

Answer (score 0):

This is a really late answer, and I'm not sure if it's still relevant for newer EC2 instances, but I've just taken over an account running Ubuntu 16, and I solved this annoyance by just adding the dns hostname to the hosts file.  Presumably this could be automated for any auto-scaling if desired.  As simple as:

```
echo 127.0.0.1 ip-10.x.x.x >> /etc/hosts
```

Or any variant using `tee` or `sed` or your other Unix tool of choice. You could include ipv6 version as well, if you really want to be thorough, but ipv4 was enough to stop the warning in my case.